# Undefined reference linking error when using &MyClass::MyFunction

Tags: c++, linker, g++, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

this just has me stumped, so I thought I'd query here:

I have a class as follows:

```
class MyClass {
    public:
        void myThreadFunc();
};
```

That's in the header. In the constructor

```
MyClass::MyClass() {
    ...
    boost::thread t(boost::bind(&MyClass::myThreadFunc, this));
    ...
}
```

As I've seen done. There are NO compile time errors. However, when I link as follows:

```
g++ -o test.exe main.o MyClass.o /*specify boost and other libraries */
```

I get:

```
MyClass.o:MyClass.cpp:(.text+0xa4): undefined reference to `MyClass::myThreadFunc()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Which doesn't make any sense. What strikes me especially odd is that's its a **linker** error. I included both of my object files.

Can anyone tell me what's going on? If it might be relevant, I'm on MinGW on Windows.

EDIT:

Epic fail. I forgot the MyClass:: prefix when defining the function in my cpp file. I just didn't decide to check that. Almost as bad as forgetting a semicolin after a class definition.

Comment: Haha, sorry! I edited the error code to make sense with my conceptual layout of the question. Didn't want to clog it with specific details of my application.

Comment: Obviously `MyClass::myThreadFunc()` is not defined or in an object file that's not included when linking. You need to add more details and/or a small sample that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @Georg Fritzsche I've changed it to the error from my small test case application, I had originally included the error from the real application in which the problem occurred.

Comment: The problem remains the same.

Comment: Also, I'm not and haven't been experiencing any problems with boost or other libraries, this has to do with my own code or linking options with my own code, apparently.

Comment: Yes, you haven't written the function.

Comment: maybe you implemented it without `MyClass::`?

Comment: ^ That's what it is. There should be a compiler warning if I try to refer to it! Just a warning would do. But I digress.

Comment: warning? why? you have the proper declaration, the definition doesn't have to be in the same compilation unit

Comment: Declarations are exactly there for the purpose that you **can** refer to things that aren't defined anywhere. That's how you can have multiple translation units.

Comment: Why should there be a warning? The compiler can't know where the actual implementation will be (same translation unit, other TU, a library, ...). Also, that's a good example of why you should **post the relevant code** to not let people *guess* on the problem.

Comment: Perhaps we could interest you in this [fashionable, sexy new language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) which doesn't have headers and forward delcarations and such nonsense. Also garbage-collected, woot.

Comment: I know I know it's my responsibility! I'm not that spoiled! C++ is just new to me, because I know everything around it: C, Objective-C, higher level languages like Java, Python, so the C++ syntax is hitting me a little hard.

Comment: @Georg Fritzsche point taken, I try to write informative and well documented questions. I'll include more original code next time instead of trying to simplify the problem. That would have found my error, anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write a function body for `MyClass::myThreadFunc()` somewhere. Writing a constructor for `MyClass` is different from implementing the `MyClass::myThreadFunc()` member function.

If you call a function in C/C++, it must have a function body somewhere. That's why it's a linker error; it's trying to find the function body in all of the available object files, but you didn't write one so it can't.